# Migrating web api authentication from .NET Core 1.1 to 2.0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to convert my old authentication to .NET 2.0. I had the following code:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    IncludeErrorDetails = true,
    Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxx",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxxx",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "xxxx",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    },
});
```

My new code is the following:

```
public void Configure(...)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxxx";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxx",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "xxxxxx",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        }); 
    ...
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthorization(......);
}
```

But in 2.0 I'm getting a 404 response. If I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute from my endpoint, it works. My output window shows this:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:62423/api/users/info
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
>   Authorization failed for user: (null).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Authorization failed for the request at filter
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing
>   ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information:
>   AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action
>   SORTE.API.ContentManager.Controllers.UsersController.Info
>   (SORTE.API.ContentManager) in 24.0837ms
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 35.2446ms 302 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET
>   http://localhost:62423/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Finfo
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 5.8149ms 404

From the log errors, it seems that it's trying to redirect me to `/Account/Login`, but I don't have such endpoint, my project is a Web API.

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, until i read [this](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2).

> When we use the Authorize attribute, it actually binds to the first authentication system by default.

The solution was especify wich scheme to use (JwtBearer):

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = "PoliceName")]
```

Now i  can get status 200 (with valid token) and 401 (unauthorized - invalid token)

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck in this problem for almost a week. Now my claims transformer is not working but that's another problem...

Comment: Wow. Wow. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot too, facing the same problem since the update to asp.net core 2.0 !